# C++: Why I get Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

struct Computer
{
    char * model;
    char * assembler;
    int processorInt;
};

int main()
{
    Computer comp;
    char* model;
    char* assembler;
    int processorInt;

    cin>>model;
    cin>>assembler;
    cin>>processor int;

    comp.model = model;
    comp.assembler = assembler;
    comp.processorInt = processorInt;

    return 0;
}
```

//if i do so, it works, BUT if i do in another way, it gives Segmentation Fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

struct Computer
{
    char * model;
    char * assembler;
    int processorInt;
};

void setValues()
{
    Computer comp;
    char* model;
    char* assembler;
    int processorInt;

    cin>>model;
    cin>>assembler;
    cin>>processor int;

    comp.model = model;
    comp.assembler = assembler;
    comp.processorInt = processorInt;
}

int main()
{
    setValues();

    return 0;
}
```

So what's the reason?

My goal is to create an array of structures in which i can save some info about each "computer", then make a possibility to edit any structure and then sort the whole array by procesorInt. But I can't even create a normal editable structure.

Comment: You're inputting to an unallocated, uninitialized pointer. You either need to make it point to some preallocated memory, allocate memory for it (which involves the first part), or, best of all, use `std::string`.

Comment: What is `cin>>processor int;`?

Comment: The first one works because you're unlucky. The second doesn't work because you're lucky.

Comment: Replace your `char *` with `std::string` and use a `std::vector` instead of an array, for a starting point. Instead of `setValues`, the name should probably be `std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Computer &c);`.

Comment: @JesseGood, A typo of `cin >> processorInt;`. I'm not sure why the OP isn't just inputting `comp.member` directly here anyway; it seems pointless keeping the temporary variables and not checking them or anything before transferring the results.

Comment: Jesse Good, sorry it's a misspell, originally it's processorInt

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, could you please explain what does it mean? I'm not getting it

Comment: @Roma Writing through unitialized pointers is undefined behaviour. There's no way to tell how a program will behave when that happens. It might *appear* to work and you'll have an unreliable buggy program but won't know it. It might print random stuff on screen or reset your computer at any random moment or anything else... A crash at least indicates something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither version works, you're trying to read data into an uninitialized pointer. Just declaring e.g. `char* model;` leaves you with a pointer that isn't initialized: it can point to any spot in memory. When you try to store a string at that location using `cin >>` you'll be writing memory that doesn't belong to you. This might segfault, or it might appear to work.

Just declaring `char*` doesn't give you space for the string: if you're using standard C strings then you'll need to give them some data: make your `char` pointers arrays of a fixed size, or use `malloc` to allocate a string buffer:

```
char model[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

Or use malloc, but be aware that you'll need to `free` this memory later:

```
char *model = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

Now, if you're going to use standard C strings and `cin` together, you shouldn't use `>>` at all: there's no way to limit the input size. Instead use [`cin.getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) with `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` as the limit (see the example in the docs for details).

But definitely prefer to use `std::string` instead: if you do so then you won't need to deal with providing space for the string yourself, and your code won't need to change much at all.

Comment: thank you for explaining, after c# this topic is something very strange for me

Comment: You can't safely read from the input into a fixed size buffer; there is no way to prevent an overrun. `std::string` is the only sensible option here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks Mike, that's definitely important and I've added a bit more about that.

Answer (score 5):

You are reading  to a `char` pointer that isn't pointing anywhere. There is no space to store the characters read.

Much easier is to use a `std::string`, beause it will automayically resize itself to hold old the characters from the input.

```
Computer comp;
std::string model;
std::string assembler;
int processorInt;

cin>>model;
cin>>assembler;
cin>>processorInt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but part of exercise is to use C-like strings

Comment: @RomaBugaian, Then I'd prefer a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. That way you still have one less problem to worry about. However, depending on whether a C string is defined as an array of characters or a pointer that you must manage yourself, you might have to opt for worse than a smart pointer.

Comment: @RomaBugaian: Then I hope the point of the exercise is to teach you about the dangers of buffer overruns and the importance of sanitising inputs. You can't safely use C-style strings with C++-style formatted input.